# Error while scraping ingramer with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to download Instagram photos through ingramer site. Here is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import os
time_to_scroll=50
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\ir\Downloads')
image_src_list=set()


b = webdriver.Chrome()
b.get('https://ingramer.com/profiles/instagram-viewer')
time.sleep(3)
search=b.find_element_by_id('downloaderform-url')
search.send_keys('my-instagram-user')
search.submit()
while time_to_scroll:
    time.sleep(10)
    image_div=b.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div')
    for div in image_div:
        try:
            image=div.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
            if image:
                image_src_list.add(image.get_attribute("src"))
        except:
            print('sonthing missed')
    nextpage=b.find_element_by_id("viewer-next-button")
    b.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",nextpage)
    nextpage.click()
    nextpage.click()
    time_to_scroll-=1
    
def downlad_image(urls):  
    count=0
    for url in urls:
        reponse = requests.get(url)
        if reponse.status_code == 200:
            with open(f"search{count+1}.jpg","wb") as file:
                file.write(reponse.content)
        count+=1
downlad_image(image_src_list)
```

But it gives this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\tamrin\python\tamrin.py", line 29, in <module>
    nextpage.click()
  File "C:\Users\ir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\ir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\ir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I am not understanding this piece `while time_to_scroll:` and above that you have defined  `time_to_scroll=50`.  So basically you are saying `while 50:`.  What is that supposed to do? I don't think it's doing what you think it is.

Comment: @JD2775it's true
I wanted to scroll down the page 50 times to load all the photos, but I do not know a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The `StaleElementReferenceException` occurs when you define an element, navigate to another page in your test, then try to use the same element again. Since the error is occurring on line 39 (your second `nextpage.click()`), I expect that the first `nextpage.click` navigates to another page, and since the `nextpage` element was defined on the previous page, you get the `StaleElementReferenceException`

Anyway, I think you can get around this by simply redefining `nextpage`, something like this (if the selector remains the same)

```
nextpage=b.find_element_by_id("viewer-next-button")
b.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",nextpage)
nextpage.click()
nextpage=b.find_element_by_id("viewer-next-button")
nextpage.click()
```